# NextJs + Prismic Slice machine: throws an error in the console when trying to open a Custom type in Slice machine

Tags: reactjs, next.js, slice, prismic.io

I encountered this problem 2 times, for the first one, I had to delete the Custom type called "Page" then recreate it.

Reproduction action:
1/ Start the local project with `yarn dev`
2/ Start the Slice machine with the command `npm run slicemachine`
3/ In the local address `http://localhost:9999/` is the administration of Slice machine
4/ In the Custom types tab, I click the "Page" one, then a page load is displayed and then an error message appeared "Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)."

When I see the console, this is the error I get in it:
`Error: Minified React error #185; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

How to solve this problem?
Thanks
[image]

I tried to read the documentation in this link but it does not solve the problem
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=185